# Converting numbers to times...Too many arguments in "if statement"

Tags: if-statement, time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to have numbers converted to times in Google Sheets.

(ex. "14325" to "1:43.25" & "5505" to "55.05")

I am trying to get it to work for both times over a minute and under a minute. I have got two formulas to work independently

```
=if(D4<99999,"00:0"&(LEFT(D4,1)&":"&(MID(D4,2,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))),"00:"&(LEFT(D4,2)&":"&(MID(D4,3,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))))
```

this works for over a minute and

```
=IF(D4<6000,"00:00:"&(LEFT(D4,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2))))
```

for under a minute.

When I try to put them together

```
=if(D4<99999,"00:0"&(LEFT(D4,1)&":"&(MID(D4,2,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))),IF(D4<6000,"00:00:"&(LEFT(D4,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))),("00:"&(LEFT(D4,2)&":"&(MID(D4,3,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2))))))
```

I get an error of too many arguments in the if statement.

I have even tried getting rid of the if greater than "99999" argument to try and reduce number

```
=if(99999>D4>6000,"00:0"&(LEFT(D4,1)&":"&(MID(D4,2,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))),IF(6000>D4,"00:00:"&(LEFT(D4,2)&"."&(RIGHT(D4,2)))))
```

but it still gives me the wrong time if under a minute. (ex. "5505" shows as "00:05:50.05").

Any ideas?

There may be a totally easier way to do this (I'm still learning formulas...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TIME(
 IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A20:A30, LEN(A20:A30)-4), 2), 0), 
         RIGHT(LEFT(A20:A30, LEN(A20:A30)-2), 2), 
              RIGHT(A20:A30, 2)), "h:mm:ss"), "^0:", )))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you need **duration** then use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(
 IFERROR(LEFT(A20:A30, LEN(A20:A30)-4), 0)&":"& 
   RIGHT(LEFT(A20:A30, LEN(A20:A30)-2), 2)&":"& 
        RIGHT(A20:A30, 2), "[h]:mm:ss"), "^0:|^:", )))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(
 IFERROR(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-6), 0)&":"&
 IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-4), 2), 0)&":"& 
         RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-2), 2)&"."& 
              RIGHT(A1:A, 2), "[h]:mm:ss.00"), 
 "^0:0:|^0:00:0|^0:00:|^0:0|^0::|^0:|^:", ), 
  IF(A1:A<>"", ".0"&A1:A, )))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE 2:

if you want to do a further calculation with times you need to have the full format:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", TEXT(
 IF(IFERROR(      LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-6))="",      0,         LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-6))&":"&
 IF(IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-4), 2))="", "00", RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-4), 2))&":"& 
 IF(IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-2), 2))="", "00", RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-2), 2))&"."& 
 IF(LEN(A1:A)>1, RIGHT(A1:A, 2), "0"&A1:A), "[h]:mm:ss.00"), ))
```

[image]

and then you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(AVERAGE(VALUE(E1:E3)), "[h]:mm:ss.00"))
```

[image: 0]

or you can do it in one go like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(AVERAGE(VALUE(IF(A1:A3<>"", TEXT(
 IF(IFERROR(      LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-6))="",      0,         LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-6))&":"&
 IF(IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-4), 2))="", "00", RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-4), 2))&":"& 
 IF(IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-2), 2))="", "00", RIGHT(LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-2), 2))&"."& 
 IF(LEN(A1:A)>1, RIGHT(A1:A, 2), "0"&A1:A), "[h]:mm:ss.00"), ))), "[h]:mm:ss.00"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: So that worked, but I am also looking for milliseconds.  I added ".00" into the  "[h]:mm:ss", but it just gave me a ".00" added to it. is there a way to make it read this? (ex. "202" would read "2.02")  Thanks!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here it is.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p8SB9tvoDi84iv012U3rY2VUSHqPw4JZKKNcOqDG9Ns/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Now there is just one more thing to it. Is there a way to make the value that it creates be a number. Changing the format isn't working. We are trying to enter multiple times for one swimmer and then find the average of those times.